# Why does The Raw Shark Texts have "negative" chapters or "un-chapters"?

Tags: steven-hall, the-raw-shark-texts

[In a forum post](http://forums.steven-hall.org/yaf_postst52_What-are--Raw-Shark-Texts-Negatives.aspx), Steven Hall, the author of *The Raw Shark Texts*, announced that each chapter of *The Raw Shark Texts* had a negative chapter:

> Hello.
>
> For each chapter in The Raw Shark Texts there is, or will be, an
>   un-chapter, a negative.
>
> Not all the negatives are as long as a novel chapter - some are only a
>   page, some are only a couple of lines. Some are much longer than any
>   chapters in the novel. Not all the negatives are online, some are, but
>   they're hiding. Some are out there in the real world, waiting to be
>   found. Anyone with the Raw Shark UK special edition will already have
>   Negative 6/36 and anyone with a Canadian edition will have Negative
>   36/36 (and also a good idea of what some of the other negatives are).
>
> The negatives are not deleted scenes, they are very much a part of the
>   novel but they are all splintered from it in some way.
>
> There's also sticky negative discussion thread for folks to chat and
>   post their findings.
>
> Happy hunting.
>
> Steven H

What is the purpose of these "negatives"?

Answer (score 2):

The forum post link seems to be dead now, but an entry on the [Thisisnotabook](http://thisisnotabook.baldurbjarnason.com/Transmedia/Unchapters.html) site discussing the entry gives a fuller version of the text than either OP’s post or Wikipedia:

> For each chapter in The Raw Shark Texts there is, or will be, an un-chapter, a negative. *If you look carefully at the novel you might be able to figure out why these un-chapters are called negatives.* Not all the negatives are as long as a full novel chapter - some are only a page, some are only a couple of lines.

I’ve emphasised the section which is additional to OP’s quote.

The entry goes on to discuss whether the unchapters are [transmedia](https://www.teachthought.com/the-future-of-learning/the-definition-of-transmedia/) and says:

> Hall’s suggestion that a careful look at the novel explains their existence can be interpreted as meaning the unchapters are the echoes of Eric’s story in our world (the book is acutely aware of its existence as a medium for story to take place in, down to the textual rendering of the shark’s appearances) and an extra-textual reification of the events of the text. They exist—and it does not matter whether we have read all or none of them—as a set of negatives from which the positive prints of the book are fashioned.

Hall himself says, of the unbook and whether it was part of the original plan for the novel, in an interview with [Structomagazine](https://structomagazine.co.uk/interviews/steven-hall/)

> It was conceived alongside it. Towards the end of writing Raw Shark, and really understanding the kind of book I was trying to write and what I wanted it to do. One of the big things in the book is about loss and incompleteness and about some things that a person can move heaven and earth to get hold of but will slip through your fingers. I just loved the idea that the book is not quite complete; that there are some things you don’t know, some things that would help you understand the book, but which are lost.

In ‘[Dissociation in the Raw Shark Texts (Stephen Hall)](https://www.academia.edu/23864918/Dissociation_in_The_Raw_Shark_Texts_Steven_Hall_?source=swp_share)’, Magrieta Wever writes:

> The author has applied many ways of showing a dissociative state, also in the
>  way the book is shaped. Apart from the visuals aspects mentioned in the former
> chapter,
> The Raw Shark Texts 
>  looks like a rather normal novel, still it has a special
> note to it; There is a large part missing, equal to the memory of Eric Sanderson. An
> inattentive reader might not notice, unaware of missing texts, but Hall has written
> some un-chapters which are not in the book, however very significant to emphasize the
> typical situation for a person that is infested with memory loss.

> These un-chapters serve as a metaphor for the memories lost; One does not know that these chapters are missing, as one is in the belief that everything one can read is right there in the book. The un-chapters were found in different places, both online and offline, at different moments in time, some still unfound. A metaphor for memory and memory loss.

> Apart from the un-chapters, there is an un-dex, serving as an index that is not contained in the novel. It contains the things a regular index does: names or definitions structured and organized neatly from A to Z, with the mentioning of the pages they appear on. This is a way of showing that if you take the book as a metaphor for Eric’s  world, this part, the retrieval cue, is missing. He is not able to sort out things well, he has no recollection, no association, so he has no index to start his memory search from.

In the end All of these perspectives are slightly different ways of saying the same thing, that a lack of completeness, or ability to completely understand the book in one neat package, is baked in by the use of unchapters, leaving the reader to share the uncertainties of the protagonist.